# Why won't my XPath work with mixed content?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

In an HTML below:

```
   <html>
        <div class="row content-box">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="gray-separator-3">
        <div class="row to-top">
          <h2 class="xs-mt-0">
            Who's covered? 
            <span class="ns-i-pencil_icon icon-flipped pensil-font"></span>
            <span>
              <a class="edit-font firefinder-match" href="#">Edit</a>
            </span>
        </h2>
        <p class="xs-mt-0 xs-mb-0">David</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  </html>
```

XPath for the 'Edit' Link **doesn't** seem to work when written as:

`//div[.//h2[contains(.,'Who's covered?')]]//span/a[.='Edit']`

but seems to work as expected when written as:

```
//div[.//h2]//span/a[.='Edit']
```

And works fine when there's no child node under `<h2>`

Like in the case below, when I write an XPath like this:

`//div[.//h2[contains(.,'What's covered?')]]//span/a[.='Edit']` it identifies the element.

```
<html>
    <div class="row content-box">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="gray-separator-3">
    <div class="row to-top">
      <h2 class="xs-mt-0">
        What's covered?
      </h2>
      <span>
        <a class="edit-font firefinder-match" href="#">Edit</a>
      </span>
      <p class="xs-mt-0 xs-mb-0">David</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Is there a reason why it doesn't read the `<h2>` which has child nodes under it along with the text?

Could anyone explain what the difference is when a node has both text and a subtree and a node which has only text but no subtree when writing an XPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This has nothing to do with mixed vs non-mixed content.**

Your first XPath is malformed.  Change it from

```
//div[.//h2[contains(.,'Who's covered?')]]//span/a[.='Edit']
```

to

```
//div[.//h2[contains(.,"Who's covered?")]]//span/a[.='Edit']
```

and it will work as you expect.

Note that if the language hosting the XPath is already using `"` to surround the XPath itself, you should be able to escape the inner `"` as thus (for Java):

```
"//div[.//h2[contains(.,\"Who's covered?\")]]//span/a[.='Edit']"
```

> And works fine when there's no child node under

No, that malformed XPath shouldn't work fine anywhere.

Comment: It does work for few cases though. Not arguing about the logic but here's an example where it works with single quotes. But this has been how I have written all the Object IDs for all the time.

http://i66.tinypic.com/2ryod3s.jpg

Comment: Sorry, but you'd have to provide a full **[mcve]**  to convince anyone that a malformed XPath "works".  See it from the XPath parser's perspective: When you encounter the `'` after `'Who`, you close off the string being built as the first argument to `contains()`; then you encounter a `s` and say, "uhh, that ain't supposed to be here."

Comment: Now that made complete sense when there's a single quote inside the single quotes. Thank you.
And it did work when I changed the single quotes to double.